# Google Gson 2.4 minifyEnable true issue

Tags: android, gson

I work on an app that currently uses google gson 1.7.1 lib. It all works fine, but i wanted to update it to the latest version. Tried updating it to 2.4 and on the debug variant of the app it works well.

I recently tried running the app on the release version and suddenly the JSON parsing mechanism is not working. Reverting the gson lib to 1.7.1 fixes the issue, but i would still want to have it updated to the latest version.

What i have noticed is that if i set `minifyEnabled` to `false` on the release version, i start getting data again (the parsing mechanism works).

Does anyone know of an issue regarding `minifyEnabled true` and the latest gson lib ?

In my proguard-rules files i have the following items related to the gson lib:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.data.beans.json.** {
    private <fields>;
}
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.myapp.ui.views.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

I also tried adding

```
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```

as per Google Gson sample [config](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) file but it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell proguard to keep the classes (fields and methods) and that will be serialized/deserialized over GSON.

For instance, if you have all your models in the package `com.google.gson.examples.android.model`, you need to add the following rule to proguard

```
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

Take a look at [this Gson proguard official example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg), and try to use those rules in your project.

Comment: I already do that with 

`-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.data.beans.json.** {
    private <fields>;
}`

I also keep the related classes (but i forgot to add them in the initial post)

Comment: try broadening the rule. The rule I posted in the answer is the broadest one, so I'd give it a go and then I'd narrow it down if it works. For instance, are you sure all the fields in the beans are private? Try removing `private` from the proguard rule.

Comment: Okay. As i have said in my previous comment, i already keep the model classes for the deserialization process. I have also removed the `private <fields>` rule. Also, yes I'm sure that all my fields are private - hence the rule.

`-keep class com.myapp.data.beans.**
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.data.beans.** { *; }`

Still does not work. Also, if the proguard config would have been wrong, the deserialization process would not have worked with the 1.7.1 version of the library.

Comment: Your problem is definitely proguard, so I was just trying to help you pin down what proguard is doing that is causing the issue. Most likely not related, but is there a particular reason why you're not upgrading to a more recent version of gson (2.7 or 2.8)? If you want, it may help if you provide the code where you create the gson instance and where you use it, and a simple example of one of your models.

Comment: So i have updated to gson 2.8 - same behaviour. I agree it must be something at proguard level, but i don't get what i'm missing since it works on older versions.

Also, here's a pastebin snippet of the code where I create a gson instance and a couple of items in my models - http://pastebin.com/xD28GdUz

Comment: "Also, yes I'm sure that all my fields are private - hence the rule" -> In the sample you provided: "protected String thumbUrl".

Comment: That was my bad...did not pay enough attention. Still, even after removing the `private` from proguard, it still does not work...

Comment: what exactly is the error message you see? Like on logcat?

Comment: Any solution found? I am still facing this issue.

Comment: any fix for this ? only occurs on release build. TIA

Comment: you can add
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}