# Kotlin: Gson.fromJson() returns null

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I would like to parse Json file using Gson library.

Some reason, method of gson.fromJson() returns null.

I have created data classes using JSON to Kotlin plugin in Android Studio and retrieve the data using Okhttp 4.9.0.

**Method:**

```
val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed your request")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val result = gson.fromJson(body, YoutubeAPIModel::class.java)
            }
        })
```

**YoutubeAPIModel class:**

```
class YoutubeAPIModel (val results: List<ApiModel>) {
}
```

**ApiModel class**

```
data class ApiModel(
    val kind: String,
    val etag: String,
    val nextPageToken: String,
    val regionCode: String,
    val pageInfo: PageInfo,
    val items: List<Item>
)
```

**Item class**

```
data class Item(
    val etag: String,
    val id: Id,
    val kind: String,
    val snippet: Snippet
)
```

**Snippet class**

```
data class Snippet(
    val channelId: String,
    val channelTitle: String,
    val description: String,
    val liveBroadcastContent: String,
    val publishTime: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val thumbnails: Thumbnails,
    val title: String
)
```

**Thumbnails class**

```
data class Thumbnails(
    val default: Default,
    val high: High,
    val medium: Medium
)
```

**Default class**

```
data class Default(
    val height: Int,
    val url: String,
    val width: Int
)
```

**Medium class**

```
 data class Medium(
    val height: Int,
    val url: String,
    val width: Int
)
```

**High class**

```
data class High(
    val height: Int,
    val url: String,
    val width: Int
)
```

**body:**

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "753UP2XJw3TXoRmm3zEGF55fGP0",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "CA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "WppfAkVnlxM77-c4C5YkSMZy8tE",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "apsAw6pzK8k"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-11-27T15:15:00Z",
        "channelId": "UClkZ3VjIiEcW0iiQsI2VCzQ",
        "title": "Justin reagiert auf Montes kranken Gamingroom.. | Reaktion",
        "description": "PESO™: https://pesoclo.com/ (werbung) Twitch: http://twitch.tv/jstinLIVE PRO: http://youtube.com/jstin17 Instagram: http://instagram.com/jstin ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/apsAw6pzK8k/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/apsAw6pzK8k/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/apsAw6pzK8k/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "justinLITE",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-11-27T15:15:00Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "JA3RfxF6EBqBmmNRxsedtOKMcJs",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "MPbUaIZAaeA"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-11-20T05:00:11Z",
        "channelId": "UC4-TgOSMJHn-LtY4zCzbQhw",
        "title": "Shawn Mendes, Justin Bieber - Monster",
        "description": "Listen to “Monster” now: https://Monster.lnk.to/Single New album WONDER from Shawn Mendes available Dec 4th Pre-order now: https://wonder.lnk.to/Album ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPbUaIZAaeA/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPbUaIZAaeA/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPbUaIZAaeA/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "ShawnMendesVEVO",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-11-20T05:00:11Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "HxnPWxJ157hcm5oisVd5m8d6AuA",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCIwFjwMjI0y7PDBVEO9-bkQ"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2007-01-15T21:17:27Z",
        "channelId": "UCIwFjwMjI0y7PDBVEO9-bkQ",
        "title": "Justin Bieber",
        "description": "Help change the world. http://monster.lnk.to/single.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnjpa2md8Bfk-LdYllfDdWWdF6CpKebvAlI5NifS6Q=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnjpa2md8Bfk-LdYllfDdWWdF6CpKebvAlI5NifS6Q=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwnjpa2md8Bfk-LdYllfDdWWdF6CpKebvAlI5NifS6Q=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Justin Bieber",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2007-01-15T21:17:27Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "W8Plz-NvW5Wu10V8eYId5iFo_QU",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "xQOO2xGQ1Pc"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-10-16T04:00:08Z",
        "channelId": "UCHkj014U2CQ2Nv0UZeYpE_A",
        "title": "Justin Bieber &amp; benny blanco - Lonely (Official Music Video)",
        "description": "Lonely is out now: http://smarturl.it/imsolonely Starring Jacob Tremblay and directed by Jake Schreier If you're feeling Lonely or know someone who is struggling ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xQOO2xGQ1Pc/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xQOO2xGQ1Pc/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xQOO2xGQ1Pc/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "JustinBieberVEVO",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-10-16T04:00:08Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "UBm6g6muHKP8ax-leC622ZCX-Sw",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "8EJ3zbKTWQ8"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-01-04T17:00:11Z",
        "channelId": "UCHkj014U2CQ2Nv0UZeYpE_A",
        "title": "Justin Bieber - Yummy (Official Video)",
        "description": "Changes Out Now: https://justinbieber.lnk.to/Changes Follow Justin: http://facebook.com/justinbieber http://twitter.com/justinbieber ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8EJ3zbKTWQ8/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8EJ3zbKTWQ8/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8EJ3zbKTWQ8/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "JustinBieberVEVO",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-01-04T17:00:11Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You might want to break down your JSON into smaller pieces and test all classes individually

Comment: Thanks, I have called the API with 1 result, but it still returns null. If you dont mind, could you instruct me how to test each class regarding with Gson?

Comment: I'd create individual test case for each class. You can copy pieces of your JSON as smaller sources for each class

Comment: I have identified the issue and solved.  It was due to key brackets in the JSON and did not parse correctly. Thank you for your suggestion to test with small parts.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in the `app/build.gradle` file, under the `buildTypes` section I had the `shrinkResources` and `minifyEnabled` keys set to `true`. I had to commentted them or set them to false in order for the **gson** library to work well. While they were set to `true` the `fromJson` method from the **gson** library always returned null.

```js
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        // shrinkResources true // Breaks gson library
        // minifyEnabled true // Breaks gson library
        zipAlignEnabled true

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        // shrinkResources true // Breaks gson library
        // minifyEnabled true // Breaks gson library
        zipAlignEnabled true

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this solution relate to Gson?

Comment: This has to do with ProGuard Rules. Here is the snippet from gson. 

"ProGuard is a tool for 'shrinking' and obfuscating compiled classes. It can rename methods and fields, or remove them if they appear to be unused. This can cause issues for Gson which uses Java reflection to access the fields of a class. It is necessary to configure ProGuard to make sure that Gson works correctly."

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42369462 and https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg for more info and examples.